# Do potentiometers exist that include DPDT switches at the limits?

Tags: switches, potentiometer

Do potentiometer packages exist that include 2 [double-pole double-throw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology) switches, one of which is switched at the lower limit, the other switched at the upper limit? (Preferably with tactile clicks.)
    I actually just want a normally closed DPST switch that is opened at the lower limit and a normally closed SPST switch that is opened at the upper limit, with each of the 2 potentiometer end terminals internally connected to a terminal on the opposite switch and the remaining 5 terminals connected to leads out of the packaging (which would only require a total of 5 leads rather than 15). This is such that power isn't unnecessarily dissipated in the resistor when at a limit, and has a free isolated switch that can be used to power-off the device or module when at the lower limit. (Note: In this instance, I'm after a logarithmic taper, but this configuration will also be useful for applications requiring a linear taper.)
    I realise that the former, more general configuration with 2 DPDT switches and no internal connections is easier to explain and is more versatile because it could be used for an application that requires normally open with the close position at a limit. The latter can easily be constructed from the former. So, do packages of either of these 2 configurations exist, or anything else that I could construct my specific configuration from?

Comment: If Bourns doesn't have one then probably no.

Comment: I have occasionally seen units with switches at both ends, but I don't think they were DPDT.  And it used to be that you could "stack" units to do a lot of weird things, but finding the parts to do that is probably hard these days (and the stackable units were always of questionable quality anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. About the closest standard unit you will find has a SPST switch at the CCW end of the rotation. These used to be common on radios, and allowed power to be switched off by turning the volume ALL the way down.

If you're willing to spend some bucks, there are custom units available. http://www.potentiometers.com/pdf/catalog70.pdf for instance, will allow you to stack a pair of effectively SPDT switch units at both the CW and CCW ends of your rotation, along with a resistive pot. This will give you what you've asked for, but I don't guarantee you'll like how much you have to spend.